# How to call another javascript inside Main JS File

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript without HTML, just JavaScript with Node and I need some other js files so it does not take up too much space on the main file. And I was looking for, and I found something like "module.exports", but I did not understand it so well, can anyone explain this to me?

I've tried this

```js
var xgr = require("./xgr.js").randomString;
randomString();
```

In the other file

```js
function randomString() {
 var carac = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * carac.length);
 var gerado = carac[rand];
 return gerado;
}

module.exports = randomString;
```

Comment: It should be `xgr()` instead of `randomString()` because that is the name you gave to the function when you've imported it.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/ take a look at this. Explains it well.

Comment: That returns a error called "xgr() is not a function"

Comment: Just declare the script you want functions fron on top of your actual script. Like this `<script type="javascript" src="script_you_want_to_reference">...</script>`  and `<script type="javascript" src="your_new_script">...</script>`

Comment: @JasonKrs What part of "without HTML" and "node" did you have trouble understanding?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't think OP said "without node"...

Comment: That first comment is not quite right, see the bottom of the answer by @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @aw04 yes, now I've realized that `require("./xgr.js")` will be the `randomString` function which means that `require("./xgr.js").randomString` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Node documentation on modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) goes into this in a fair amount of detail.

Essentially, `exports` (also available as `module.exports`) is a predefined object in a module you can add properties to that you want to export. (Or you can replace the whole thing if you prefer.)

`require` retrieves the exports of the file you `require`.

So if `a.js` is:

```
exports.foo = function() {
    console.log("Hi there");
};
```

and `b.js` has

```
var a = require("./a");
```

then

```
a.foo();
```

...outputs `"Hi there"`.

---

With your example `xgr.js`:

```
function randomString() {
    var carac = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * carac.length);
    var gerado = carac[rand];
    return gerado;
}

module.exports = randomString;
```

you're replacing `exports` entirely. You'd use it like this:

```
var randomString = require("./xgr.js");

console.log(randomString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good way to share your functions between components

```
var _public = exports;
_public.randomString = function () {
    let carac = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * carac.length);
    let gerado = carac[rand];
    return gerado;
}
```

So you can use all your shared functions like this

```
let xgr = require("./xgr.js");
xgr.randomString();
```